# Get JSON with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm trying to perform a *GET* request to my API endpoint, which returns a JSON response. How do I do this?

Controller.js

```
 oknok.controller('listagemController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.init = function () {
        $http.get("/api/veiculos")
            .then(function (data) {
                alert(data.toJSON());
            }).catch(function (error) {
                alert("Erro ao obter dados!");
            });
    }
});
```

Response from API when I execute curl in terminal

```
curl http://localhost:8181/api/veiculos
{
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8181/api/veiculos"
    }
  },
  "_embedded" : {
    "veiculos" : [ {
      "nome" : "daniela",
      "tipo" : "tipo",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8181/api/veiculos/559d59b1ccf2ebb2fc97e70e"
        },
        "contatos" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8181/api/veiculos/559d59b1ccf2ebb2fc97e70e/contatos"
        },
        "clientes" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8181/api/veiculos/559d59b1ccf2ebb2fc97e70e/clientes"
        }
      }
    } ]
  },
  "page" : {
    "size" : 20,
    "totalElements" : 1,
    "totalPages" : 1,
    "number" : 0
  }
}
```

Comment: any console errors ?

Comment: @K.Toress No , I get status 200

Comment: didn't you get the alert in success callback ?

Comment: @K.Toress I changed my script for the Chrillewoodz suggested and now I get error code

Comment: @K.Toress I replace for `JSON.stringify` and works! How do I get "nome" and "tipo" from veículo? Only access _embedded, veículo...?

Comment: updated my answer please have a look.

Comment: @DanielaMarquesdeMorais You can get "nome" and "tipo" from veiculo like this : var json = JSON.stringify(data);
               var nome = json.embedded.veiculos[0].nome;
               var tipo= json.embedded.veiculos[0].tipo;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you getting the data successfully but seems like there is some exception when you tring to alert is.

use `JSON.stringify(data)` instead of `data.toJSON()`

```
$scope.init = function () {
    $http.get("/api/veiculos")
        .then(function (data) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        }).catch(function (error) {
            alert("Erro ao obter dados!");
        });
}
```

How do I get "nome" and "tipo" from veículo?

```
// get the _embedded property of the object (data)
var embedded = data._embedded;

//get the veiculos property of the embedded object
var veiculos = embedded.veiculos;

//get the nome & tipo (veiculos is a array so you need to refer the first index to do that use veiculos[0])
var nome = veiculos[0].nome;
var tipo = veiculos[0].tipo;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
oknok.controller('listagemController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.init = function () {
        $http.get("/api/veiculos")
            .then(function (data) {
                alert(data.toJSON());
            }).catch(function (error) {
                alert("Erro ao obter dados!");
            });
    }
});
```

You need to use `.then` and `.catch` instead of `.success` and `.error`.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can't use alert in that way but you can use console.log instead.

```
 oknok.controller('listagemController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.init = function () {
        $http.get("/api/veiculos")
            .then(function (data) {
                console.log(data.toJSON());
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.log("Erro ao obter dados!");
            });
    }
});
```